# Trying to extract data from multiple websites at once but can't

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-extraction

I have a dataset of 110,003 churches in the US. The dataset includes the name of the church together with other details. I need to populate a column with the date of opening. This requires Googling each church to find its date of opening and populating each row. I am posting an example dataset with 10,000 cases. Please help!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B1db58lmP5nK1ZeJPEJTuYnPjGTxfu_74RG1IELLsP0/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried using import.io and scrapy but they don't seem to work for me as well as I would appreciate if you recommend a better tool.

Comment: You can use BeautifulSoup library in Python to scrape the date of opening. An example of web-scraping using BeautifulSoup can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIPqt-OdmS0

Comment: Google uses JavaScript to add items on page. When you turn off JavaScript in browser then you see different page and BeautifulSoup/lxml and requests see this page - they can't run JavaScript. But problem can be that Google easily recognizes bots/scripts and blocks them. Some portals offer proxy servers for scraping Google page.

Comment: thank you for your response *but the link that you guys have shared has only 4 videos and that too they are static,mostly about html tags,  what I have posted requires pagination and multiple websites